# How can I compare two python lists by index return a Boolean if the index in each string matches?

Tags: python, list, indexing, boolean

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
```

Desired output

```
False
False
False
False
True
```

Comment: You can use `zip` function.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]

for first, second in zip(a, b):
    print(first == second)
```

Keep in mind this is assuming `a` and `b` are the same length. Otherwise it will only iterate over the shorter of both lists.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly! I’ve never used zip. I’m super appreciative of the answer and glad to look into it for future reference as well.